# LINQ Projection in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda

I posted a couple of questions about filtering in an eager loading query, and I guess the EF does not support filtering inside of the `Include` statement, so I came up with this.

I want to perform a simple query where get a `ChildProdcut` by sku number and it `PriceTiers` that are filtered for `IsActive`.

```
Dim ChildProduct = ChildProductRepository.Query.
            Where(Function(x) x.Sku = Sku).
            Select(Function(x) New With {
                       .ChildProduct = x,
                       .PriceTiers = x.PriceTiers.
                       Where(Function(y) y.IsActive).
                       OrderBy(Function(y) y.QuantityStart)
                   }).Select(Function(x) x.ChildProduct).Single
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I am on the right track at all? It does work.

Another thing I really don't understand is why does this work? Do you just have to load an object graph and the EF will pick up on that and see that these collections belong to the ChildProduct even though they are inside of an anonymous type?

Also, what are the standards for formatting a long LINQ expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Is there a more efficient way of doing this? I am on the right track at all?`

Nope, that's about the way you do this in EF and yes, you're on the right track.

`Another thing I really don't understand is why does this work?`

This is considered to be a bit of a hack, but it works because EF analyzes the whole expression and generates one query (it would look about the same as if you just used `Include`, but with the `PriceTiers` collection filtered). As a result, you get your `ChildProducts` with the `PriceTiers` populated (and correctly filtered). Obviously, you don't need the `PriceTiers` property of your anonymous class (you discard it by just selecting `x.ChildProduct`), but adding it to the LINQ query tells EF to add the `join` and the extra `where` to the generated SQL. As a result, the `ChildProduct` contains all you need.

Answer (score 0):

If this functionality is critcal, create a stored procedure and link entity framework to it.

Comment: Would you happen to have an example of this?